# Table line not displaying on browser but able to display if print to pdf file

Tags: html, css, html-table

Any ideas why my code is not displaying the table lines on browser? Appreciate any help!

Below is my CSS & HTML:

```css
@page {
  size: auto;
  /* auto is the initial value */
  margin: 0px;
}
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape
  }
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><small>Customer's PO Numer:</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>
      <center>T/15526/CS/001R3</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><small>Customer's V.O Numer:</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>
      <center>NIL</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><small>No. of CT PO raised for same supplier and project (prior to this PO)</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'><u><center>3</center></u>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><small>Amount raised for same supplier and project (prior to this PO)</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>
      <center>$610.23</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have attached the error here! Please have a look. Furthermore, I have tried my code on IE too. Not working.

[image: Browser view]

[image: Print to PDF]

Comment: table line displays correctly for me

Comment: Could it be my browser? Using google chrome.

Comment: Did saw a table border as you set  border: 3px solid black;

Comment: Try to wrap it in div tag then put a border at table itself or div tag to simulate where is your table location

Comment: It's working fine, can you attach screenshot of your issue? or might be other css overriding this css.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot. Please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

You should write in css file as.

```
table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Changed it, still not displaying on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

its working for me. you forgot to use  in header.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape
  }
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><small>Customer's PO Numer:</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>
      <center>T/15526/CS/001R3</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><small>Customer's V.O Numer:</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>
      <center>NIL</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><small>No. of CT PO raised for same supplier and project (prior to this PO)</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'><u><center>3</center></u>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><small>Amount raised for same supplier and project (prior to this PO)</small>
    </td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>
      <center>$610.23</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check where your table is?

```html
<div style="border:3px solid #A52A2A"> 

your table here

</div>
```

Comment: So you mean, you don't have a problem now? coz your table shows eventually.